# How to fix a timeout error in mongodb on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows, mongodb, server, port, firewall

Hello world developer team,

I have a problem connecting to a MongoDB Community Edition database. From the same server I can connect using localhost or 127.0.0.1, with Mongo Shell, but when I connect through the IP assigned to the server (from inside or outside), it is generating a timeput error. The ports have already been opened in the Firewall as indicated by the official MongoDB guide.

Next I leave the logs and data of the environment. Thank you very much for your help.

**CONFIG FILE MONGODB**

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\data
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path:  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\log\mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  #bindIp: server.sdtruckingllc.com
  ipv6: true
  bindIpAll: true

#processManagement:

#security:

#security:
  #authorization: enabled

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

**SERVER**

[Information server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2LlZ.png)

**ERROR MONGODB SHELL**

[Error into shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdS3c.png)

**LOG**

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:43.718-05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"main","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:43.721-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22615,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Loading library: {toUtf8String_full_path_c_str}","attr":{"toUtf8String_full_path_c_str":"Schannel.dll"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:43.722-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.050-05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.051-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.051-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":10508,"port":27017,"dbPath":"C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/4.4/data","architecture":"64-bit","host":"SERVER"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.051-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.051-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.1","gitVersion":"ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.051-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows Server 2016","version":"10.0 (build 14393)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.051-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"mongod.cfg","net":{"bindIp":"*","ipv6":true,"port":27017},"storage":{"dbPath":"C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\4.4\\data","journal":{"enabled":true}},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\4.4\\log\\mongod.log","verbosity":1}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.052-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":23104,   "ctx":"OCSPManagerHTTP-0","msg":"Starting thread","attr":{"threadName":"OCSPManagerHTTP-0","poolName":"OCSPManagerHTTP"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.053-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/4.4/data","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.053-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=3513M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.173-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1602091484:173127][10508:140706605586896], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 28 through 29"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.227-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1602091484:226910][10508:140706605586896], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 29 through 29"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.284-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1602091484:284572][10508:140706605586896], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Main recovery loop: starting at 28/4224 to 29/256"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.378-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1602091484:377373][10508:140706605586896], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 28 through 29"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.465-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1602091484:465355][10508:140706605586896], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 29 through 29"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.512-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1602091484:512339][10508:140706605586896], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.512-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1602091484:512339][10508:140706605586896], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.657-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":604}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.657-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.658-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"COMMAND",  "id":23098,   "ctx":"WTIdleSessionSweeper","msg":"BackgroundJob starting","attr":{"threadName":"WTIdleSessionSweeper"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.658-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22303,   "ctx":"WTIdleSessionSweeper","msg":"starting {name} thread","attr":{"name":"WTIdleSessionSweeper"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.670-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20280,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Registering collection","attr":{"namespace":"admin.system.version","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"c5e4924a-9b07-4f40-9be0-8ce5a8051318"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.670-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20280,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Registering collection","attr":{"namespace":"local.startup_log","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"8c3cd903-2013-4d11-9bdc-e0680b40cca3"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.670-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20280,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Registering collection","attr":{"namespace":"config.system.sessions","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"56050db2-2538-45d8-9c1b-994d854244fb"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.671-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20280,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Registering collection","attr":{"namespace":"admin.system.users","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"64e544c2-2e20-4a8d-a433-9811f88aa7de"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.671-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.671-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"COMMAND",  "id":23098,   "ctx":"WTJournalFlusher","msg":"BackgroundJob starting","attr":{"threadName":"WTJournalFlusher"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.671-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22305,   "ctx":"WTJournalFlusher","msg":"starting {name} thread","attr":{"name":"WTJournalFlusher"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.671-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"COMMAND",  "id":23098,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"BackgroundJob starting","attr":{"threadName":"WTCheckpointThread"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.671-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22307,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"Starting thread","attr":{"threadName":"WTCheckpointThread"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.715-05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.722-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20907,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing plan cache - collection info cache reset","attr":{"namespace":"admin.system.users"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.723-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20907,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing plan cache - collection info cache reset","attr":{"namespace":"admin.system.version"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.723-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"-",        "id":22546,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Reloading view catalog for database","attr":{"db":"admin"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.724-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20907,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing plan cache - collection info cache reset","attr":{"namespace":"config.system.sessions"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.724-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"-",        "id":22546,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Reloading view catalog for database","attr":{"db":"config"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.724-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20907,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing plan cache - collection info cache reset","attr":{"namespace":"local.startup_log"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.724-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"-",        "id":22546,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Reloading view catalog for database","attr":{"db":"local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.724-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"STORAGE",  "id":21010,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"    Recovering database: {dbName}","attr":{"dbName":"admin"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.780-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"STORAGE",  "id":21010,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"    Recovering database: {dbName}","attr":{"dbName":"config"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.780-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"STORAGE",  "id":21010,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"    Recovering database: {dbName}","attr":{"dbName":"local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.780-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"STORAGE",  "id":21017,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"done repairDatabases"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.780-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.781-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"admin.system.roles","command":{"find":"system.roles","readConcern":{},"$db":"admin"},"planSummary":"EOF","keysExamined":0,"docsExamined":0,"cursorExhausted":true,"numYields":0,"nreturned":0,"reslen":107,"locks":{"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"r":2}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}},"readConcern":{"provenance":"clientSupplied"},"storage":{"data":{"bytesRead":345}},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.781-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20227,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"There were no users to pin, not starting tracker thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.781-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":23104,   "ctx":"AuthorizationManager-0","msg":"Starting thread","attr":{"threadName":"AuthorizationManager-0","poolName":"AuthorizationManager"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.921-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/4.4/data/diagnostic.data"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.921-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"COMMAND",  "id":23098,   "ctx":"PeriodicTaskRunner","msg":"BackgroundJob starting","attr":{"threadName":"PeriodicTaskRunner"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.921-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":23104,   "ctx":"FreeMonHTTP-0","msg":"Starting thread","attr":{"threadName":"FreeMonHTTP-0","poolName":"FreeMonHTTP"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.921-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"COMMAND",  "id":23098,   "ctx":"TTLMonitor","msg":"BackgroundJob starting","attr":{"threadName":"TTLMonitor"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.922-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"COMMAND",  "id":23098,   "ctx":"ClientCursorMonitor","msg":"BackgroundJob starting","attr":{"threadName":"ClientCursorMonitor"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.922-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"config.system.sessions","command":{"listIndexes":"system.sessions","cursor":{},"$db":"config"},"numYields":0,"reslen":245,"locks":{"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}},"storage":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.923-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"config.system.sessions","command":{"listIndexes":"system.sessions","cursor":{},"$db":"config"},"numYields":0,"reslen":245,"locks":{"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}},"storage":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.923-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"0.0.0.0"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.923-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"config.transactions","command":{"find":"transactions","filter":{"lastWriteDate":{"$lt":{"$date":"2020-10-07T16:54:44.923Z"}}},"projection":{"_id":1},"sort":{"_id":1},"readConcern":{},"$db":"config"},"planSummary":"EOF","keysExamined":0,"docsExamined":0,"cursorExhausted":true,"numYields":0,"nreturned":0,"reslen":108,"locks":{"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"r":2}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}},"readConcern":{"provenance":"clientSupplied"},"storage":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.923-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"::"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:24:44.923-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:25:14.781-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":23106,   "ctx":"AuthorizationManager-0","msg":"Reaping this thread","attr":{"nextThreadRetirementDate":{"$date":"2020-10-07T17:25:44.781Z"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:25:14.782-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":23105,   "ctx":"AuthorizationManager-0","msg":"Shutting down thread","attr":{"threadName":"AuthorizationManager-0","poolName":"AuthorizationManager"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:25:44.922-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"INDEX",    "id":22533,   "ctx":"TTLMonitor","msg":"ns: {collectionNSS} key: {key} name: {name}","attr":{"collectionNSS":"config.system.sessions","key":{"lastUse":1},"name":"lsidTTLIndex"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:25:44.947-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"INDEX",    "id":22536,   "ctx":"TTLMonitor","msg":"deleted: {numDeleted}","attr":{"numDeleted":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:26:44.948-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"INDEX",    "id":22533,   "ctx":"TTLMonitor","msg":"ns: {collectionNSS} key: {key} name: {name}","attr":{"collectionNSS":"config.system.sessions","key":{"lastUse":1},"name":"lsidTTLIndex"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:26:44.948-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"INDEX",    "id":22536,   "ctx":"TTLMonitor","msg":"deleted: {numDeleted}","attr":{"numDeleted":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:27:44.951-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"INDEX",    "id":22533,   "ctx":"TTLMonitor","msg":"ns: {collectionNSS} key: {key} name: {name}","attr":{"collectionNSS":"config.system.sessions","key":{"lastUse":1},"name":"lsidTTLIndex"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:27:44.951-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"INDEX",    "id":22536,   "ctx":"TTLMonitor","msg":"deleted: {numDeleted}","attr":{"numDeleted":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:28:44.952-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"INDEX",    "id":22533,   "ctx":"TTLMonitor","msg":"ns: {collectionNSS} key: {key} name: {name}","attr":{"collectionNSS":"config.system.sessions","key":{"lastUse":1},"name":"lsidTTLIndex"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-07T12:28:44.953-05:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"INDEX",    "id":22536,   "ctx":"TTLMonitor","msg":"deleted: {numDeleted}","attr":{"numDeleted":0}}
```